# Passing Pointer to an Array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, xc8

This is for MPLABXC8 compiler
I have researched and found number of topics related. But not able to solve my issue.
My Array typedef

```
     typedef volatile struct OneStageOpTag
   {
        unsigned DevID1: 4;
        unsigned SetCmd1 : 4;
        unsigned RdyResponse1 :4;
        unsigned DevID2: 4;
        unsigned SetCmd2 : 4;
        unsigned RdyResponse2 :4;
        unsigned DevID3: 4;
        unsigned SetCmd3 : 4;
        unsigned RdyResponse3 :4;
    }OneStageOpType[3];
```

Now my variable

```
    OneStageOpType CurOperPlan={0};// I checked this one - 
        //-in Simulator 3 element array of structure created
```

Now I am passing pointer to my function

```
GetOperationSeqForTransportReq(1,1,&CurOperPlan);
```

below is the function

```
void GetOperationSeqForTransportReq(StationIDType SourseStnID,StationIDType DestiStnID,
                    OneStageOpType  *CurTransportPlan)
{
    NOP();
    CurTransportPlan[0]->DevID1=5;  // This is Ok
    CurTransportPlan[1]->DevID1=5;  // This is Not working      
}
```

only the 0th element is accessable. Also compiler complaints that structure pointer passed to structure array pointer.
I tried by incrimenting the pointer in function. It seems incrimenting the whole Array pointer.
It seems to me that `&CurOperPlan` is adress pointer to 0th index structure only. The whole array is not contained it.
please help.

Comment: Start by _not_ typedeffing arrays.

Comment: Remember that the array itself is a pointer. You are dereferencing a pointer (the array) here: `GetOperationSeqForTransportReq(1,1,&CurOperPlan);` either use `GetOperationSeqForTransportReq(1,1,CurOperPlan);` or `(*CurTransportPlan)[0]->DevID1=5;` with the type `OneStageOpTag *`.

Comment: As @ThomasPadron-McCarthy pointed out - your code took a wrong turn the moment you `typedef`ed an array.

Comment: This code is a part of this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214847/typedef-ing-a-array-of-structure-in-c?noredirect=1#comment60065139_36214847
I am using that typedef to create a two dimentional array in ROM.
Not able to find another way.

Comment: GetOperationSeqForTransportReq(1,1,CurOperPlan); // Not working (*CurTransportPlan)[0]->DevID1=5;// Not compiling

Actually I need to create a two dimentional array of a ' array of structures'. May be I am doing this in the wrong way. trying to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: @Myst: "*Remember that the array itself is a pointer*" no, it isn't really. And array just *decays* to a pointer to its 1st element under certain conditions, for example it does when getting passed to a function.

Comment: @alk , no offense, but you're slightly missing the point. Arrays in C are implemented as pointers, they degrade to pointers when passed as function arguments and behave exactly like pointers except for compile-time instructions (i.e. `sizeof`). So, when the array `CurOperPlan` was passed to the function `GetOperationSeqForTransportReq`, it was passed as a pointer to the first instance.

Comment: @Myst: "*[arrays] behave exactly like pointers*" Ever successfully assigned to an array? Ever applied any arithmetics to an array? Also there is a significant difference between the address of an array and the address of a pointer in terms of the resulting type.

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
GetOperationSeqForTransportReq(1,1,&CurOperPlan);
```

to be

```
GetOperationSeqForTransportReq(1, 1, CurOperPlan);
```

and this

```
void GetOperationSeqForTransportReq(StationIDType SourseStnID,StationIDType DestiStnID,
                OneStageOpType  *CurTransportPlan)
```

to be this

```
void GetOperationSeqForTransportReq(
  StationIDType SourseStnID,
  StationIDType DestiStnID,
  OneStageOpType CurTransportPlan)
```

---

For completeness also change this

```
OneStageOpType CurOperPlan={0};
```

to be

```
OneStageOpType CurOperPlan = {{0}};
```

Comment: `{0}` is a correct idiom to zero-initialize an aggregate in all cases.   IMHO sticking to common idioms is not a bad idea.   There were some earlier versions of gcc that warned about incomplete bracing for `{0}` but I believe they have been updated now to not give that bogus warning.

Comment: @M.M: "*they have been updated now to not give that bogus warning*" Really? Great! :-) I perhaps should update though ... :}

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function, you need:

```
(*CurTransportPlan)[0].DevID1=5;  // This is Ok
(*CurTransportPlan)[1].DevID1=5;
```

This is because `CurTransportPlan` is a **pointer** to your array. So you must dereference it to get the array.  Then you can apply array indexing to the array.

[Link to working example](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g520,options:'-pedantic+-O3+-Wall+-std%3Dc11+-x+c+-pedantic',sourcez:AQFwngDgpgJlBmwBuB7ANgQxASzVYAziAE4CuAxiMAPIB2UAyiBgOZTUQAqrAUMPwG8%2B/Ef1K0C2FvRjAAIlCQBJOQEYAXMAAsAbmGixEqTOAMoIAMIBbGKuCbd%2Bg%2BMnTYwAEowwHqAQgoElB26o4GIi7G7grKcgBMDnrhhq4mZpY2cfbaScmRbrJePn4BQVmhueH5JjEqAMyJTqLV7unWMHXZYXlGBZ7evv6BBFCdFU4AvnSMzGwcnJBQANp1ALp6PKjYsgDi5hxQxFjYgWYAjgBiKMScRxIBxCC%2BZwAU00ys7FyL/ABUFqQbncho8AAqYWgASh4QlEL3%2BgNuGHu1xA4ORkKWAAZVgA6WpqAC8AFYdPwAPTk4CcAAW2AIwHpNAA1k54QCgciQWiIZjVHiCaoSWTgJTqXSGUyAHIoKgAd2uzOwtBY4R4Ex4PGVVCsGGVL2hsJE71mXwW0GAHIOxHRtEJAixE0qwD2IGtx1OUEu1yRKMezxeADIrdAbby9BqgAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

---

To explain why the first one seemed to work, we can rewrite the code applying the equivalence transformations `X->Y` = `(*X).Y`, and `X[N]` = `*(X+N)`.

The correct indexing in array notation should be `CurTransportPlan[0][0].DevID1` and `CurTransportPlan[0][1].DevID1`  ; however your code swapped the indices in both cases. This meant the first one still worked but the second one broke.

---

Regarding your code design:  it's been noted that there are two ways to approach passing an array to a function:

1. You can pass a pointer to the first element of the array, as alk suggests (passing the length separately, or hard-coding it)
2. You can pass a pointer to the entire array as you are currently doing.

I will list some of the differences between these two designs.  Using your design, i.e. the pointer-to-whole-array:

- You get a compilation error if an array with a different number of rows is passed.
- You get a compilation error if a non-volatile array is passed.
- You must write `(*ptr)` instead of `ptr`, which is slightly more verbose.

The decision for you to make is whether you want the compiler to give errors in those first two points.   The errors can be avoided by casting, but generally speaking, need to cast is a sign that the other approach would have been a better design.

If this function is only ever to be used with the size-`3` `volatile` array then IMHO your current approach is the best one,  invoking maximum compiler detection of errors.

Comment: Agreed, however I do not think the OP intended to actually implement this additional indirection.

Comment: Nice :-) - one may add, that for the 2nd design it also is possible to change the value being passed in "by reference" inside the function.

Comment: (*CurTransportPlan)[0].DevID1=5;  
(*CurTransportPlan)[1].DevID1=5;
This i not compiling in my case

Error   [209] D:\UB_Wrks\PLC_Dmain\PTS_Shammy\Firmware\BlowerUnit\PTS_BlowerUnit.X\PTS_DataSetModule.c; 28.22 type conflict
Error   [981] D:\UB_Wrks\PLC_Dmain\PTS_Shammy\Firmware\BlowerUnit\PTS_BlowerUnit.X\PTS_DataSetModule.c; 28.23 pointer required
Error   [981] D:\UB_Wrks\PLC_Dmain\PTS_Shammy\Firmware\BlowerUnit\PTS_BlowerUnit.X\PTS_DataSetModule.c; 28.23 pointer required
(908) exit status = 1

Comment: @user2454516 I included link to working example in the first part of my answer, compare your code with that to see if you made a typo somewhere.  I guess maybe you removed `*` as an earlier answer suggested, but didn't put it back when trying mine out

Comment: @MM. Sorry for the mistake before .the code is working. Now I am testing two approaches. One is passing the element and incrimenting the pointer to get the next index. Seems ok. In the calliing argument compiler (MPLAB XC8 is not making any complaints if I use  "CurOperPlan or &CurOperPlan" it works.
But When I use the passing array as the argument method, I am getting data loaded correctly wuth your method
(*CurTransportPlan)[0].DevID1=5;  // This is Ok
But compiler complains about illegal pointer conversion in the calling line if I use & or without.

Comment: investigate how you are invoking the compiler, only one of `X` and `&X` can ever be right. Perhaps you are also missing out on other important messages because it is configured to hide some errors.

Comment: @user2454516 copy and paste the exact code from my sample into a .c file and compile it with your compiler and see what it says.  If it gives an error then your compiler has a bug.

Comment: Link to that working example takes me to acompiler page. But I cant see the relevent code there. How to find your example there?

Comment: @user2454516 when you click it you should get a compiler page with the code on the lefthand side in a pane titled "Code editor". If you don't then I can't really help further

Answer (score -1):

As you have a typedef of three elements array:

```
typedef volatile struct OneStageOpTag {
  // ...
} OneStageOpType[3];
```

The problem looks to be:

```
void GetOperationSeqForTransportReq(
  StationIDType SourseStnID,
  StationIDType DestiStnID,
  OneStageOpType *CurTransportPlan)       // HERE
```

In above function you are declaring parameter as a pointer to 3-element array, but you should pass it as a pointer to first element of array. This means you should do the following instead:

```
typedef volatile struct _OneStageOpTag {
  // ...
} Array[3], Element;

// ...

Array CurOperPlan={0};
GetOperationSeqForTransportReq(1,1,&CurOperPlan);

// ...

void GetOperationSeqForTransportReq(StationIDType SourseStnID,
  StationIDType DestiStnID, Element *CurTransportPlan)
{
  NOP();
  CurTransportPlan[0]->DevID1=5;  // This is Ok
  CurTransportPlan[1]->DevID1=5;  // This is Not working      
}
```

This should works fine for you :)

Comment: Thanks. It is working, but with slight diffference.
since  "CurTransportPlan" is now a pointer to a element, [0] or [1] is not possible.
CurTransportPlan->DevID1=5;// this works and then
Incriment the pointer
CurTransportPlan++;
CurTransportPlan->DevID1=6;// this now modifies the [1] element.
Only thing array is available as seperate elements in this case.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Passing `&CurOperPlan` is not correct as it evaluates to a pointer to the array itself, but what you want is a pointer to its fist element, so just pass `CurOperPlan`. The compiler should warn about this. Any ways the code might still work as the value of the address of an array is always the same as the value of the address of the array's 1st element ...

Comment: Passing a pointer to the element and then incrimenting this pointer to get the other two elements seems working alright.
CurOperPlan or  &CurOperPlan is not making any practical difference when element is being used. So it seems.
But in any case when I pass   CurOperPlan or  &CurOperPlan, the indexing is not available in the destination function.
Thanks

Comment: @user2454516 one of the two cases would give a compiler error or warning (note: any such "warning" is actually an error). You should make sure you have a clean compile with no errors or warnings before running the code.

Comment: as far as I can understand  "&CurOperPlan" is the address of the Array and   "CurOperPlan"   is the address of the first element of this array.
But whern I can passing  "&CurOperPlan" as the address of array , still compiler complains. This is when the receiving function expects the pointer at array. If receiving side expects a pinter to the element of this array compiler is happy with both methods. Any Clue?